# Outlook365 - Shared mailbox login

Tags: email, outlook, office365

I need to setup email sending from shared mailbox using *EWS/Exchange.asmx* in custom application and don't have idea how to pass username and password.

- Outlook 356
- Shared mailbox: **shared@outlook.com**
- User address: **user@outlook.com**  (with license and full access to
  shared... I can log into shared using web client)

Parameters to enter in the app are:

- Host / URL -> https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
- Domain -> domainname
- Username -> ?????
- Password -> domain password for user@outlook.com

How to fill username to log into shared using user password? I've tried some combinations like: user@outlook.com\shared etc. but it is not working (unauthorized error). When I enter just user's name and pass email is sent correctly, but I need message to be sent from shared mailbox address.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use "user@outlook.com\shared@outlook.com" as the username. You can use POP3 or IMAP. Here is an examaple which uses OpenPop package:

```
    private string hostname = "pop-mail.outlook.com";
    private int port = 995;
    private bool useSsl = true;
    private string username = "user@outlook.com\\shared@outlook.com";
    private string password = "YourPassword";

    public List<Message> FetchAllMessages()
    {
        // The client disconnects from the server when being disposed
        using(Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
        {
            // Connect to the server
            client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl);

            // Authenticate ourselves towards the server
            client.Authenticate(username, password);

            // Get the number of messages in the inbox
            int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();

            // We want to download all messages
            List<Message> allMessages = new List<Message>(messageCount);
```